# R Data Grouping

Tags: r, group-by

I have a table of data. Col 1 Case Number, Col 2 Group and Col 3 actual values. I want group-wise summaries of this data in R. So if I have three groups I can do

```
m1=subset(m,group == 1)

m2=subset(m,group == 2)

m3=subset(m,group == 3)
```

and then

```
summary(m1)

summary(m2)

summary(m3)
```

I am looking for a shortcut to these sets of commands, so that I can do it for any number of groups in my data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that `group` has only 3 levels (distinct/unique values), you can do

```
lapply(split(m, group), summary)
```

Comment: Thanks @aL3xa it worked with small modification 
`lapply(split(m, m$group), summary)`

Comment: `library(plyr); dlply(m, "group", summary)` is an option

Comment: And now how do I pass parameters to the function say I want to run `shapiro.test()` on Col 3 which is value in my data table.

Comment: It depends... usually you'd like to pass just after function name, as an additional formal parameter: `lapply(split(m, m$group), fn, param1, param2)`. This is possible thanks to `...` parameter. Sometimes you need to pass a simple anonymous function to make magic happen. But, anyway, `stats::shapiro.test` takes only one argument! O_o

Comment: @Vijay - I'd recommend looking further into plyr package...I'd answer your specific question with something like `dlply(m, "group", function(x) shaprio.test(x$Col3))`. I'd add sample data to your question and explain exactly what it is you need too, comments aren't really designed to be the source of answers.